# How to tell intel graphics to use my custom EDID file?

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, edid

As the topic says:

How to tell intel graphics to use my custom EDID file?

Comment: Doesn't seems to be related to UNIX or Linux

Comment: xorg is related to unix or linux, and it allows you to specify a custom EDID file for the monitor.

Comment: Same issue with `intel` over here http://superuser.com/questions/1145585/missing-modeline-when-using-passive-2-ports-vga-switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about X, you can add a `CustomEDID` option to the `Monitor` section of your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.  For example, I have the following in xorg.conf on my mythtv box:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "LG 42LD560"
    VendorName "GSM"
    ModelName "LG TV"

    Option "UseEDID" "True"
    Option "CustomEDID" "DFP-1:/etc/X11/LG-42LD560.edid.bin"
EndSection
```

I did this years ago and I can't remember where i got the edid file from.  I think I may have extracted it with `get-edid` from the debian package of [read-edid](http://www.polypux.org/projects/read-edid/) (I very vaguely recall something about getting a corrupted edid in X but it was OK if fetched from a VT before X started)

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want to do. I already have the EDID binary for my monitor but have heard that intel drivers _might_ not support custom EDID's like NVIDIA and AMD does. At the moment I use my custom EDID with a NVIDIA card under Debian, but want to take that old Nvidia card out and use the onboard Intel graphics.

Comment: I doubt `CustomEDID` apply to `Monitor` section...

Comment: Where do you think it would apply?  for the mouse?  your doubt means little in the face of several years of actual experience that X worked (and still does) correctly with my LG TV using a custom edid file in the Monitor section and didn't without it.  It means even less when you take into account the **fact** that the CustomEDID option is specifically intended for use within the Monitor section.

Comment: I can confirm what malat said: both `UseEDID` and `CustomEDID` must be in the `Device` Section. Intel ignores `UseEDID` while `CustomEDID` is totaly broken in my braswell.

Answer (score 0):

The one that worked for me :

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Device0"
   BusID       "PCI:00:02:0"
   Option      "LVDS-1" "MonitorLVDS1"
   Option      "DP-1"   "MonitorDP1"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "CustomEDID" "DP1:/etc/X11/edid.bin"
   Option      "UseEDID" "true"
EndSection
```

see full problem and solution : [Second monitor not recognized - xorg.conf file [resolved]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496553/second-monitor-not-recognized-xorg-conf-file-resolved)