# Second monitor not recognized - xorg.conf file

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, multi-monitor, xrandr, edid

I'm trying to use this monitor Acer XB270H, with my Ubuntu laptop, but it is not recognized, appears cropped with incorrect resolution.

*Note: I first was using the docking station with the monitor DP cable, and bought a mini DP to DP cable to be able to plug directly the computer to the monitor instead : but no change, it was not a hardware problem.*

I tried to force a new configuration with `xrandr` :

`cvt 1920 1080` :

```
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

**Here what shows up :**

```
gsd-color[2315]: unable to get EDID for xrandr-DP1: unable to get EDID for output
```

So, following command turns the second monitor black showing `'no signal'` :

```
xrandr --output DP1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

---

**SPECS**

`Linux 4.18.0-13-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`lspci -v | grep VGA` :

````
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])```
````

`inxi -Gxx` :

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           chip ID: 8086:0166 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.1 driver: i915 compositor: gnome-shell 
           resolution: 1366x768~60Hz, 1024x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile v: 4.2 Mesa 18.2.2 compat-v: 3.0 
           direct render: Yes
```

---

**UPDATE :**

I'm now trying to use a `xorg.conf` file as proposed.

To get the EDID I could not use `read-edid`, `parse-edid` : `/sys/class/drm/card0-DP1/edid : Partial Read... Try again...`, and could not find it on Internet.

I finally managed to get the EDID (256-bits) file from **Windows** with `moninfo.exe` tool :

```
ls -al /etc/X11/edid.bin
-rwxr----- 1 root root 256 Feb  3 14:00 /etc/X11/edid.bin
```

I tried to follow some Xorg guides, but this error came up too many times :

`gsd-color[2995]: failed to get edid: unable to get EDID for output`

Comment: Could you please post your `xorg.conf`?

Comment: Could you pls elaborate on your last problem? Are you trying to move an window from one display to another(Do you have a desktop for each monitor or single desktop spanning monitors? I don't see any accepted answer yet?!

Comment: Using some programs such as chrome, thunderbird, if I try to move the window, on the same monitor, for just a pixel, it crashes (I assume server x), and get back to login screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your log says it is not able to read `EDID` for your display port, I assume to your external monitor. Intel requires you to supply `EDID` config via `xorg.conf`, at least that is what I can pull up from my memory.

May I recommend you to try the old school way of having your `xorg.conf`.

Try creating a `xorg.conf`, if one does not exists you can create one under `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen 0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Touchpad0" "SendCoreEvents"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
#    ModeLine       "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 75.0
    VertRefresh     60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor1"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "<Vendor_Name>"
    ModelName      "<Model_Name>"
#    ModeLine       "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 75.0
    VertRefresh     60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "<Device_Identifier>"
    Driver         "<i915!?>"
    VendorName     "Intel Corporation"

    Option         "UseEdidDpi" "FALSE" # Make it TRUE and in the next line supply that
    Option         "CustomEDID" "DFP-2:/etc/X11/<EDID_config_from_Screen_Manufacturer>.bin"
    Option         "DPI"    "150x155"

Section "Screen0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1600x900 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
#        Mode        "1600x900_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen0"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
#        Mode        "1920x1080_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I am sure you might need to edit the above file, however it would give you an start. Try and post back your success/hurdles.

**FOLLOW-UP**

*As to the line-51*:
I understand it as you're trying to map your monitor to the display. If so, create a `Device` section and specify the monitor and the video card. Like the below:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Device0"
    Option      "Monitor0" "DVI" # Use your settings
    Option      "Monitor1" "DP2"
    Driver      "intel"
EndSection
```

What are the other line numbers, you have trouble with? Are you able to login through `X`?

**EDID**

You can read this link

[How to tell intel graphics to use my custom EDID file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295784/how-to-tell-intel-graphics-to-use-my-custom-edid-file)

Comment: Good to hear that you're making progress! May be you can have all your comments in the original question so people for whom it might be useful in future. I am adding my comments under my answer

Comment: Honestly I have not tried connecting through a docking station before. I am sorry I can't help you on this.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add my solution to this problem. I couldnt try the EDID-solution of DependencyHell, because I got no windows on my machine.
Dual monitors with two identical 24" monitors always worked perfectly with 1920x1080. Strangely, after connecting the third also identical monitor the second monitor was not working anymore with 1920x1080. Even after connecting it to different ports(DP-1 or DP-3 or HDMI-0), still the same error. "dmesg | grep EDID" said:

```
nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: Unable to read EDID for display device HDMI-0
```

Finally, I was able to solve the problem with a special xorg.conf:

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor1"
  VendorName     "Unknown"
  ModelName      "Acer B246HL"
  HorizSync       30.0 - 80.0
  VertRefresh     55.0 - 76.0
  Option         "DPMS"
  Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor2"
  VendorName     "Unknown"
  ModelName    "Acer B246HL"
  HorizSync       30.0 - 80.0
  VertRefresh     55.0 - 76.0
  Option         "DPMS"
  Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor3"
  VendorName     "Unknown"
  ModelName    "Acer B246HL"
  HorizSync       30.0 - 80.0
  VertRefresh     55.0 - 76.0
  Option         "DPMS"
  Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Device"
  Identifier "Card0"
  Driver "nvidia"
  Option "DP-1" "Monitor1"
  Option "DP-3" "Monitor2"
  Option "HDMI-0" "Monitor3"
  BusID "PCI:39:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Screen0"
  Device "Card0"
  Monitor "Monitor1"
  Monitor "Monitor2"
  Monitor "Monitor3"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080_60.00"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

The modeline can be generated with:

```
cvt 1920 1080
```

The rest should be self-explaining. Please ask if there are questions left.

This was the only solution that worked for me, everything with xrandr started to generate errors after the "xrandr --addmode" command.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the question provided the following solution.

> **I finally found the solution following the idea of to the answer below**. I have to tell that I had a hard time to know what to specify in this `xorg.conf` file to finally make it work.
>
> Examples, guides and documentation are not very precise about what is mandatory, what is not and the right values.
>
> ---
>
> - **Problem 1**: retrieve the Monitor EDID
> - **Solution** : use Windows with `moninfo.exe` tool.
>
> ---
>
> - **Problem 2**: configure a proper `xorg.conf` file
> - **Solution** : do not generate a complicated one, but just fill the necessary, with multiple tests... (i.e: xorg was crashing on moving certain program windows, or opening a second app...)
>
> **/etc/X11/xorg.conf :**
>
> ```
> Section "Monitor"
>   Identifier  "MonitorLVDS1"
>   VendorName  "Monitor Vendor"
>   ModelName   "Monitor Model"
> EndSection
>
> Section "Monitor"
>   Identifier  "MonitorDP1"
>   VendorName  "Acer"
>   ModelName   "XB270H"
>   Option  "Right Of" "MonitorLVDS1"
> EndSection
>
> Section "Device"
>   Identifier  "Device0"
>   BusID       "PCI:00:02:0"
>   Option      "LVDS-1" "MonitorLVDS1"
>   Option      "DP-1"   "MonitorDP1"
>   Driver      "intel"
>   Option      "CustomEDID" "DP1:/etc/X11/edid.bin"
>   Option      "UseEDID" "true"
> EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
>   Identifier      "Screen0"
>   Device          "Device0"
>   DefaultDepth    24
>   SubSection "Display"
>       Depth           24
>       Virtual   3286 1200
>   EndSubSection
> EndSection
>
> Section "ServerLayout"
>   Identifier      "Default Layout"
>   Screen          "Screen0"
> EndSection
> ```